# Excel formula for calculating occurrences per day

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to calculate the number of occurrences per day for several columns of data.

Here's an example of my data set:

[Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06Die.png)

Here's how I need to present it:

[Present data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hywVp.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post your data examples as text instead of images, and include what you have tried already. See [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Cell W3 of Sheet 2, use the COUNTIFS formula to achieve the desired result. You might need to change the sheet name in the below example or column names.

```
=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!$B:$B,'Sheet2'!$A3,'Sheet1'!$A:$A,'Sheet2'!W$2)
```

and just drag this formula to the right and down and you'll get the desired results.